# Get GridFS files by tags stored in metadata

Tags: c#, mongodb, metadata, gridfs

I have an web application that should store uploaded files with `GridFS`in a specified `MongoDB`. The files have several metadata. One is a `Tags` collection. To write the metadata for the file into `MongoDB` the code is like this:

```
BsonDocument metadataDocument = new BsonDocument(false);
metadataDocument.Add("Version", myVersionNumber);
...
metadataDocument.Add("Tags", new BsonArray(myTags)); // myTags is List<string>

MongoGridFSCreateOptions options = new MongoGridFSCreateOptions();
options.Metadata = metadataDocument;
```

This is just to demonstrate how the metadata is generated. How to upload the file to `MongoDB` is just plain code, nothing special about that.

I now want to have a method that returns all files with specified tags. This should be **case-insensitive**.

```
public IEnumerable<MyDocument> GetFilesByTag(IEnumerable<string> tags)
{
    // find all files that have at least one tag from the provided list
    // in it's tag metadata array
    ...
    return result;
}
```

Any ideas about that?

Comment: Your trying too hard in  the wrong area. A `GridFS` file is just another MongoDB document. It lives in a collection, which is by default `fs.files`. So just query that collection for the information you need.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Yes I do know that. But then, how do I query this information? I tried some stuff but can't get the information.

Comment: I don't have any clue about C#, but in the shell you'd do `db.fs.files({"metadata.someField":{$regex: /tagToFind/i}})`

Comment: If you "know that" then how hard is it to query a collection of a know name? Seems you don't "know that" at all. Is that really the question? Because it's a very easy duplicate to find.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg This is ok, but I do not search for a single tag. The method `GetFilesByTag` can provide more than one tag.

Comment: @BlakesSeven See comment above. The query is not just querying a collection for a known name.

Comment: @SimonLinder For logical `$or`, use `$in: [/tag1/i,/tagN/i]` when querying the field. For logical `$and`, use the operator `$and:[{"metadata.someField":/tag1/i}, {"metadata.someField":/tagN/i}]`.